# PHP - Getting arguments from inside brackets

Tags: php, arguments, brackets

Im trying to get information set inside some brackets...

Example:

```
[Article title="Article 1" show="Article Name Goes Here"]
<p>Some other simple text here...</p>
[Article title="Article 2" show="Article Name Goes Here"]
```

Im trying to set the "arguments" into variables so i can grab the Article 1 information from the database and replace it in the FullContent.

Comment: You'll need to look in to preg_match and regular expressions to do something like this, or you could use explode.

Comment: "replace it in the FullContent." where is the full content...?
what do you mean by arguement?

Comment: $FullContent all the text saved in the database... When i get the "FullContent" from the database i save it into the variable and then i replace all the [] functions.

Answer (score 0):

use explode or substring. substr is probably quicker and less error prone.

```
$string = '[Article title="Article 1" show="Article Name Goes Here"]';
$arg1 = substr($string, strrpos($string, "title=")+len("title="), strrpos($string, "show="));
$arg2 = substr($string, strrpos($string, "show=")+len("title="), strrpos($string, -1));
```

You may have to play around with some of the strrpos values, as I didnt take into account the qoutemarks.